# Enable remote MySQL database connections on Centos7

Tags: mysql, centos7

I am attempting to allow a remote connection to a MySQL server I have setup on my Centos7 machine. Currently when I attempt to connect I get the following error:

```
Host '[ip]' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.
```

Through my research I found it suggested I modify the `bind-address` parameter in my conf file, which wasn't present. This led me to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76511/mysql-enable-remote-connection-in-centos-my-cnf-does-not-have-bind-address-to-co#) where it is specified that

> The default address is 0.0.0.0.

and

> If the address is 0.0.0.0, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv4 interfaces.

This should mean that by default, I should be permitted to connect with a user I made (I granted all privileges to this user). Does anyone know where I am messing up? What I need to do?

---

### Aside

When I run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'bind_address'`
I get this as a result:

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| bind_address  | *     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You should not open MySQL port to public because it is a security risk. If you need to access a remo0te MySQL server, you should do it over SSH tunnel. This will handle encryption and authentication in a secure way.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen This just for development, i’ll likely close it once i migrate them into the same system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a user as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287559/mysql-adding-user-for-remote-access)

> `CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';`
>
> `CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';`
>
> Then
>
> `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';`
>
> `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%'; flush privileges;`

and adding `bind-address: 0.0.0.0` to my `my.conf` file (with a properly configured firewall of course.) Fixed my issue.